# Error: Statement expected, found Py:ELIF_KEYWORD

Tags: python

Quite new to coding and I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game. I'm trying to get it to loop back around to the start when it is done, and print the amount of wins and losses the player has. Keep getting errors that I have no clue how to fix and it's getting slightly frustrating.

Any help would be great! :)

[The Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAT48.png)

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gf98.png)

---

```
import random

loss = 0
wins = 0
rps = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
op = random.choice(rps)
print(op)

while True:
 pl = str(input("Choose your weapon! Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")).upper()
 print(f"Wins: {wins}")
 print(f"Losses: {loss}\n")

 if pl in ["PAPER", "P"] and op in ["Paper"]:
  print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nIt's a draw!")

 elif pl in ["PAPER", "P"] and op in ["Rock"]:
  print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nYou Win!")
  wins += 1

 elif pl in ["PAPER", "P"] and op in ["Scissors"]:
  print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nYou Lose!")
 loss += 1

 elif pl in ["ROCK", "R"] and op in ["Rock"]:
 print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nIt's a draw!")

 elif pl in ["ROCK", "R"] and op in ["Scissors"]:
 print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nYou Win!")
 wins += 1

 elif pl in ["ROCK", "R"] and op in ["Paper"]:
 print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nYou Lose!")
 loss += 1


 elif pl in ["SCISSORS", "S"] and op in ["Scissors"]:
 print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nIt's a draw!")

elif pl in ["SCISSORS", "S"] and op in ["Rock"]:
 print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nYou Lose!")
loss += 1

elif pl in ["SCISSORS", "S"] and op in ["Paper"]:
 print(f"Opponent has chosen {op}!\nYou Win!")
 wins += 1
```

Comment: In multiple places, you have `loss += 1` not indented enough. It must be aligned with the lines above it.

Comment: Your indentation is broken starting from the "paper"/"scissors" case: `loss += 1` is on the first text column instead of being indented. As far as Python is concerned that means the entire if/elif block has ended, leading to the following `elif` being unexpected. Fixing this will lead to every following `elif` clause breaking, because none of them are indented (and an `elif` *must* have a body).

Comment: That aside, an indentation of a single space is... unconventional. And difficult to read. The Python standard is to use 4 spaces. On most editors, the `[TAB]` key will do that for you, if the editor is not smart enough to properly indent following a `:` (most are).

Comment: An other issue you'll likely have: you only draw the opponent's hand once, so after the first bout the player can trivially achieve a 100% win rate (doesn't really matter currently since you're printing the opponent's hand beforehand anyway). Also the output of `input` in Python 3 is a string, you don't need to convert it back to a string.